# How to Format a Cell in Excel to Display Values From Active Column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was wondering how to format a cell to display the value of another cell within the column currently being used. The cell to be formatted would be separate from the active column.

Comment: I think you cannot "format" a cell to do that... you may to write VBA code and listen to Worksheet_SelectionChange event

Comment: Could a formula do the job?

Comment: @BenLake, I'm unable to understand that why U need Cell Format for,, *a cell to display the value of another cell* , there is no connection between Cell Format & get Value from another Cell !!

Comment: −1 and VTC as unclear for not fixing the oxymoronic “format a cell to display the value of another cell” wording, despite being repeatedly asked to do so, for not explaining the cryptic “another cell within the column currently being used”, for not giving an example (despite being asked to do so), and for accepting an answer that solves a problem that’s so unclear from the wording of the question.  The accepted answer may have helped the OP, but this is not a valuable addition to our knowledge base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I would like to suggest VBA Macro will help you to copy the Cell Value & Font Color of the Cell been Double Clicked into another Cell in different Column.*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:E")) Is Nothing Then
    Cancel = True

    If Application.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B"), Target.Value) = 0 Then
        Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value = Target.Value
        Cells(Target.Row, 2).Font.color = Target.Font.color
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- Press **Alt+F11** to open VB editor.
- **Copy** & **Paste** this code with the Sheet ( 
  *in this sample code `Sheet is 1`, you may 
  alter Sheet Name as your need* ), as Standard 
  Module.
- As soon you Double Click any Cell in 
  Columns `C to E`, this Code will `Copy` 
  it's Value along with `Font color` to 
  adjacent Cell in `Column B`.

**N.B.**

- Source Columns `C` to `E` are editable.
- In `Cells(Target.Row, 2)` the `2` indicates 
  Column `B`, and it's editable also.
- You can use `Target.Interior.Color` to copy 
  `Background color`.

Comment: Thank you Rajesh, that is what I needed.

Comment: Glad to help you @BenLake,, keep asking ☺

Comment: Write your concern why this post has been down voted,, help me to put my views & improve !!

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your question is for example you want cell **E5** display the value of cell **D4**. So put this formula in cell **E5**:

```
=D4
```

Correct me if i was wrong. I couldn't put comment yet because my reputation is not enough.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm asking. The cell in question to be formatted or have a new formula inserted is dependent on previously/currently entered information from selected cells within only the actively used column. As the user goes from one column to another, the displayed values in the cell in question here would also change according to whichever column is actively being used.

Comment: Can you give some example?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want a cell (e.g., `E5`)
to display a dynamically updated value based on the current selection
(i.e., the cursor), so it would change
as the user moved around the worksheet
with the cursor keys (and/or by clicking on cells),
then I’m pretty sure that’s impossible. 
It’s definitely impossible to do with a formula,
and I don’t know how a (VBA) macro
can capture the motion of the selection / cursor.

But, please, either stop using the word “format”
or explain why you believe that it’s appropriate. 
In Excel, “format” refers to bold, italic, color, etc.,
and you don’t seem to be asking about that at all.